# In column generation is it possible that a new column from sub problem doesn't enter master's base?

Tags: column-generation

In some iterations, when a new column is added to the master, it does not enter the base and a stop condition occurs, or a new column with a better objective function is found. is it correct?

Comment: Welcome to OR.SE. Would you please, explain more about what you want? If you defined the master, sub, and also the adding procedure correctly, then as long as the sub-problem can produce a column with an appropriate reduced cost, it can be added to the master, whether it has been a basic column or just being a feasible one.